# Subword vectors to a word vector tokenized by Sentencepiece

Tags: nlp, word-embedding

There are some embedding models that have used the **Sentencepiece** model for tokenization. So they give subword vectors for unknown words that are not in the vocabulary. But I want to get word vector for each word like Word2vec, fastText.
**Should I average subword vectors to represent a word vector?**

Comment: Why are you interested in those word vectors? It helps to answer your question if we know what you ultimately want do do. Can you edit your question accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have done some experiments on similar lines, averaging all subword
  embeddings has better cosine similarity to the synonym of a whole
  word.
- So yes **averaging makes sense and best option with tokenizers like
  wordpiece and sentencepiece**

Comment: Thank u so much for sharing your knowledge about this topic. Should I normalize those subword vectors before averaging for "cosine similarity" and "Keras embedding layer"?

Comment: No its not needed, since embeddings for subwords comes through the same layers there will be minimal difference in mean and variance. So a simple average should do the job.

Comment: Thank you @Hari Prasad